# JBoss 10 when I change XML to JSON format to send data from client to REST endpoint I get in client java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, json, rest, jboss

I am trying to write a simple REST endpoint (@POST) which receives class instance object packed in JSon and adds it to a List. 
As long as I use XML format, the code works correctly, but when I try to change it into JSon, wildly returns an error about a missing library. 
I tried adding boss-deployment-structure.xml and exclude libraries but it does not work. I tried manually adding java.rs library to /modules/org/ folder, but again, it did not work. 
I use RESTeasy library, I am not allowed to use Jersey.

This is the error message I receive when I try sending a Son object to the endpoint. It appears on the client side.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy_jaxrs/i18n/LogMessages
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.write.   To(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:138)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:129)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:118)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:322)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:509)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.buildEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:475)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:374)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:232)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:388)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:195)
at pl.edu.agh.kis.Main.sendData(Main.java:95)
at pl.edu.agh.kis.Main.main(Main.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n.LogMessages
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 14 more
```

When I load a project on wild fly 10, here are the messages from the server. There are some warnings there, but I cannot find on the internet information how to solve the problems that wild fly warns me about.

```
/Applications/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8   com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper  /private/var/folders/zq/19w4ng_s3db2xlzgvgrv56wc0000gn/T/idea_classpath  com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 51972 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss71Agent
 [2017-05-10 12:25:44,066] Artifact rest-ear:ear: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server admin port: 9990
Detected server http port: 8080
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /Applications/wildfly-10.1.0.Final

  JAVA:     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

12:25:48,630 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
12:25:59,014 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
12:25:59,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
12:26:00,633 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
12:26:00,670 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
12:26:00,680 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
12:26:00,712 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
12:26:00,718 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
12:26:00,721 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
12:26:00,716 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
12:26:00,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
12:26:00,754 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
12:26:00,799 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
12:26:00,818 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
12:26:00,834 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
12:26:00,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
12:26:00,885 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
12:26:00,885 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
12:26:00,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
12:26:00,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
12:26:00,961 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.0)
12:26:00,964 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgresql
12:26:01,093 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/Applications/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
12:26:01,181 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
12:26:01,268 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
12:26:01,277 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
12:26:01,469 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
12:26:01,469 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
12:26:01,522 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
maj 10, 2017 12:26:01 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
maj 10, 2017 12:26:02 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
12:26:02,041 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /Applications/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
12:26:02,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Applications/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
12:26:02,377 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
12:26:02,411 INFO    [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder]  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:26:02,411 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:26:02,411 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:26:02,412 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:26:02,413 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:26:02,413 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
maj 10, 2017 12:26:02 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
12:26:02,569 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
12:26:02,861 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
12:26:11,906 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/PostgresDS]
12:26:11,907 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
12:26:12,133 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
12:26:12,134 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:26:12,135 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 24133ms - Started 339 of 585 services (394 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
 Connected to server
[2017-05-10 12:26:12,423] Artifact rest-ear:ear: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
12:26:12,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "rest-ear.ear" (runtime-name: "rest-ear.ear")
12:26:12,860 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "rest-soap.jar")
12:26:12,860 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "rest-rest.war")
12:26:14,526 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /content/rest-ear.ear/rest-rest.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:26:14,527 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /content/rest-ear.ear/rest-rest.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:26:14,528 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /content/rest-ear.ear/rest-rest.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:26:14,599 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0091: -ds.xml file deployments are deprecated. Support may be removed in a future version.
12:26:15,028 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary
12:26:15,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/restDS]
12:26:15,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'rest-ear.ear/rest-soap.jar#primary'
12:26:15,174 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment rest-ear.ear
12:26:15,185 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper]      (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo      [
    name: primary
    ...]
12:26:15,271 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
12:26:15,342 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.10.Final}
12:26:15,347 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
12:26:15,349 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
12:26:15,459 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
12:26:15,500 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment rest-soap.jar
12:26:15,611 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment rest-rest.war
12:26:15,629 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'UpdateStudent' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "rest-rest.war" of deployment "rest-ear.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/rest-ear/rest-rest/UpdateStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.UpdateStudent
    java:app/rest-rest/UpdateStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.UpdateStudent
    java:module/UpdateStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.UpdateStudent
    java:global/rest-ear/rest-rest/UpdateStudent
    java:app/rest-rest/UpdateStudent
    java:module/UpdateStudent

12:26:15,632 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'AddStudent' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "rest-rest.war" of deployment "rest-ear.ear"' are as follows:

java:global/rest-ear/rest-rest/AddStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.AddStudent
java:app/rest-rest/AddStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.AddStudent
java:module/AddStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.AddStudent
java:global/rest-ear/rest-rest/AddStudent
java:app/rest-rest/AddStudent
java:module/AddStudent

12:26:15,632 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'RemoveStudent' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "rest-rest.war" of deployment "rest-ear.ear"' are as follows:

java:global/rest-ear/rest-rest/RemoveStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.RemoveStudent
java:app/rest-rest/RemoveStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.RemoveStudent
java:module/RemoveStudent!pl.edu.kis.agh.RemoveStudent
java:global/rest-ear/rest-rest/RemoveStudent
java:app/rest-rest/RemoveStudent
java:module/RemoveStudent

12:26:15,772 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
12:26:16,107 INFO   [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder]  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:26:16,108 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:26:16,141 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'rest-ear.ear/rest-soap.jar#primary'
12:26:16,569 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
12:26:16,577 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
12:26:16,667 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
12:26:16,672 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) Envers integration enabled? : true
12:26:17,315 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
12:26:17,323 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) HHH000230: Schema export complete
12:26:18,128 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-001125: Illegal bean type org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider<javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<?>> ignored on [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @Provider @Consumes @ApplicationScoped @Produces class   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBElementProvider
12:26:18,132 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-001125: Illegal bean type interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<?>> ignored on [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @Provider @Consumes @ApplicationScoped  @Produces class  org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBElementProvider
12:26:18,133 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-001125: Illegal bean type interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<?>> ignored on [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @Provider @Consumes @ApplicationScoped  @Produces class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBElementProvider
12:26:18,133 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-001125: Illegal bean type class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.AbstractEntityProvider<javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<?>> ignored on [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @Provider @Consumes @ApplicationScoped @Produces class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBElementProvider
12:26:18,200 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 3) WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider is annotated with @ApplicationScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
12:26:18,208 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher is annotated with @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
12:26:18,865 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context ''
12:26:20,696 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs:main. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi]
12:26:20,908 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider:main. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi]
12:26:21,180 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,190 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource pl.edu.kis.agh.Hello from Application class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,190 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource pl.edu.kis.agh.UpdateStudent from Application class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,191 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class pl.edu.kis.agh.Message from Application class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,191 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorld from Application class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,191 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource pl.edu.kis.agh.AddStudent from Application class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,191 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource pl.edu.kis.agh.RemoveStudent from Application class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,191 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource pl.edu.kis.agh.ArrayOfArrays from Application class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,191 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource pl.edu.kis.agh.AuthenticateUser from Application class pl.edu.kis.agh.HelloWorldApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
12:26:21,263 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /
12:26:21,289 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 4) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "rest-ear.ear" (runtime-name : "rest-ear.ear")
[2017-05-10 12:26:21,305] Artifact rest-ear:ear: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-05-10 12:26:21,305] Artifact rest-ear:ear: Deploy took 8 882 milliseconds
```

Here is the server class that creates the endpoint in question.

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Path("/AddStudent")
@Stateless

public class AddStudent {

    private MyArrayList students = new MyArrayList();
    private ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response dodajMiska(Student student) throws IOException {


        for (Student x : students.getRealMap()) {
            if (x.getIndexNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(student.getIndexNumber()))
                return Response.status(302).entity("Student already added to database").build();
        }

        for (Object o : student.getCourses()) {
            Course temp = new Course(((Course) o).getName(), ((Course) o).getEcts());
            courses.add(temp);
        }

        DecodeToImage decoder = new DecodeToImage();
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = decoder.decode(student.getPath());
        String pathName = "/Users/user/Desktop/REST_PROJEKT_2/tokens/rest/rest-rest/pics/" + student.getFirstName() + student.getSurname() + ".jpg";
        File outputfile = new File(pathName);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

        Student nowy = new Student(student.getFirstName(), student.getSurname(), student.getIndexNumber(), student.getLogin(), student.getPassword(), courses, pathName);
        students.put(nowy);

        Integer k = students.wielk();
        if (k == 0) {
            return  Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Student not added to database").build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(201).entity("Student added to database").build();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the client method.

```
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static Response sendData() {

        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        String path = "http://localhost:8080/examples/AddStudent";
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(path));

        String s = "/Users/user/Desktop/REST_PROJEKT_2/tokens/restClient/src/pics/pic.jpg";
        String codedPic = FileSenderApache.Send(s);
        Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(new Student.Builder().firstName("Asia").surname("Kuku").indexNumber("1234").login("popo").password("kuku").courses(new Course.Builder().name("SOA").ects(4).build()).courses(new   Course.Builder().name("SD").ects(3).build()).path(codedPic).build(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        System.out.println(response.getStatus());
        response.close();
       return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError typically are thrown because the class is not in the classpath, which could be because of the packaging of the application or the classloader isolation settings specified. Look at Class Location to locate where it is packaged and compare to the isolation settings & Java EE classpath defined for the particular deployment type.

NoClassDefFoundError is thrown when the JVM tries to load a definition of a class and no definition can be found. NoClassDefFoundError is caused by typically a ClassNotFoundException

Note: if the class does not exist in the application and the java source file does not list the class, decompile the class using javap or other decompiler and see if the class definition matches the source. Some IDEs can generate invalid classes when the classpath is missing classes, they could generate a class with invalid class references and if those get deployed it will cause unusual ClassNotFoundExceptions such as a class name with no package.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a conflict because widlfly and my program versions of resteasy and javaxrs ?

Comment: Yes. Its very much possible to have multiple versions of resteasy and javaxrs libraries present inside app server and application classpath